# Getting input value that has its own iterated button upon click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've successfully added an iterator to my php foreach loop so that I can create a unique button for each row in my table.

```
<?php $i = 1;?>
@foreach($getPromoCodes as $codes)

    <input type="hidden" name="promo_code_id" id="promo_code_id[{{$i}}]" class="promo_code_id" value="{{ $codes->promo_codet_id }}">

<?php $i++;?>
@endforeach
```

However, I can't figure out, once the button is pressed, how to get the value of the input from the clicked button. This being due to the uniqueness of each button with the iterator.

```
var promo_codet_id = document.getElementsByClassName("promo_code_id");
```

This returns undefined when I console log it.

How do I need to change my JS for this?

Comment: If `getpromocodes` is not associative you could just do `as $i => $codes`

Comment: This is because you element is not registered in `DOM`, like i proposed it does looks for the link no meter how many was added. it listen for the event happened in area of `div` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
<div class="elements">
    <?php $i = 1;?>
    <?php foreach($getPromoCodes as $codes): ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="promo_code_id" id="promo_code_id[{{$i}}]" class="promo_code_id" value="{{ $codes->promo_codet_id }}">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-id="<?= $i ?>">Link </a>

        <?php $i++;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.elements').on('click', '.btn', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **this.value** in a call to a javascript function:

```
<input type="hidden" name="promo_code_id" id="promo_code_id[{{$i}}]" class="promo_code_id" value="{{ $codes->promo_codet_id }}" onclick="doSomething(this.value); return false;">
```